# Non-specific string replacement in php

Tags: php, string

Essentially, I am trying to replace part of a string as long as it has the preceding part, but it might have something between the part that I need to check and the part I'm replacing

```
$file = str_replace('<a href=', '<a href=?pagename=',$file);
```

This code will catch most instances, but if I run into something like

```
<a class="irrelevant" href=......
```

it will not be able to catch it, is there a simple fix to this problem?

EDIT: More specifically, I am looking to only replace  tagged links, not other elements on the page such as CSS links

Comment: See PHP `preg_replace`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: If you're working with HTML, it would probably be best to use an HTML parser rather than deal with it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to replace `<a`. This is good enough:

```
$file = str_replace('href=', 'href=?pagename=',$file);
```

Comment: I am looking to replace only things that are in links, (I don't want to replace links that lead to CSS and the sort